# Processing - The printer is not responding

Tags: brother

Using Ubuntu 1604 and Brother MFC 8890DW Tje print queue states: "Processing - The printer is not responding."

In order to print I have to physically have to turn the printer off and on.  After a few minutes it will print.

What needs to be done?  I have already installed the printer multiple times.